# Replacing multiple string values in SAS

Tags: string, replace, sas, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that I'm trying to clean up. One variable is gender where I have 'F','Female,'M','Male' and 'Unknown' as values. I want to change all the iterations of 'F' to show as 'Female' and all the 'M' values to show as 'Male'. I also have another variable called 'Ethnicity' which has values such as '1 - White' but I want it to show as 'White'.

I have tried to use tranwrd

```
gender=tranwrd(gender, "F", "Female");
```

But this replaces the 'Female' values as well to 'Femaleemale'

I have also attempted index:

```
IF index(lowcase(gender),"f") THEN gender="Female";
IF index(lowcase(gender),"m") THEN gender="male";
```

But the multiple If statements don't work.

Comment: Be sure to run a `Proc FREQ` against your data so you have a list of all the discrete values and how often they occur.  The variations observed in the bin values can offer strategies for dealing with new data, or an explicit list for the basis of creating a correction mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered `TRANWRD` is the wrong function for the value transformation task at hand.  Neither is `INDEX` because the true value in SAS is the state of non-zero and non-missing -- `INDEX(`*`source, excerpt`*`)` result will be a logical true for the case of finding the *`excerpt`* **anywhere** in *`source`*.

For specific value transformations use a direct literal value for comparison.  For testing a specific single character you can do the lowercase as you show, or use an `IN` list.

```
  if gender in ('M', 'm') then gender = 'Male'; else
  if gender in ('F', 'f') then gender = 'Female';
```

For the case of extracting `ethnicity` from a value construct *`# - ethnicity`* you can , per @draycut, use the `COMPRESS` function with the *keep alphabetic characters only* option (`ka`).

Another way to transform patterned values is to use regular expression search and replace.

```
   * replace leading # - before embedded ethnicity with no string (//);
   ethnicity = prxchange ('/^\d+\s*-\s*//',1,ethnicity);
```

Answer (score 1):

See if you can use this as a template

```
data have;
input gender $ 1-7 Ethnicity $ 9-18;
datalines;
F       1 - White
Female  White    
Male    2 - Black
Unknown Black    
m       1 - White
f       1 - White
;

data want;
   set have;

   if upcase(char(gender, 1)) = "M" then gender = "Male";
   else if upcase(char(gender, 1)) = "F" then gender = "Female";
   else gender = "Unknown";

   Ethnicity = compress(Ethnicity, , 'ka');
run;
```